# Changing variables in integration over spheres

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Suppose we would like to change variables in the integral

$$I:=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}f(\omega_1,\omega_2,...,\omega_{n})d\sigma_{n-1},$$

where
$\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is the standard unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $n\geq 2$,   $d\sigma_{n-1}$ is the surface measure induced by the Lebesgue measure on  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and
$\left(\omega_{1}(\theta_{1},...,\theta_{n-1}),
\omega_{2}(\theta_{1},...,\theta_{n-1}),...,\omega_{n}(\theta_{1},...,\theta_{n-1})\right)$ is a unit vector that gives the parametric spherical representation of every point $(x_1,...,x_n)$ that lies on the sphere.
So, for example, every $(x,y)\in\mathbb{S}^{1}$ has the representation
$(x,y)=(\omega_1,\omega_2)=(\cos{\theta_{1}},\sin{\theta_1})$, $\theta_{1}\in [0,2\pi]$, and every $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{S}^{2}$ has the representation
$(x,y,z)=(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3)=(\sin{\theta_{1}}\cos{\theta_2},\sin{\theta_1}\sin{\theta_{2}},\cos{\theta_{1}})$, $\theta_{1}\in[0,\pi], \theta_{2}\in[0,2\pi]$.

Question: How to change variables in the integral $I$? My question is about the Jacobian. Precisely, if we change variables $\omega_{i}=\phi_{i}(\omega_{1},\omega_{2},...,\omega_{n})$ where $\phi_{i}$ are continuously differentiable and invertible, is it correct that

$$I=\int_{\cup_{\theta_1,\theta_2,...,\theta_{n-1}}{(\phi_{1},...,\phi_{n})}} f(\phi_{1},...,\phi_{n})\det\left(\frac{\partial(\omega_1,...,\omega_n)}{\partial(\phi_1,...,\phi_n)}\right)\,d\sigma_{n-1} ?$$

Comment: Do NOT use the same letters for the original variables and the new variables. Nor should you write partial derivatives with respect to functions.

Comment: Thank you prof. Shifrin. The old variables are the $\omega_i$, $i=1,...,n$ and the new variables are $\phi_i$, $i=1,...,n$. The second part "Nor should you write partial derivatives with respect to functions" is unclear to me. We naturally see  the  new variables as functions of the old variables (and vice versa) when we compute the Jacobian.

Comment: No, the $\phi_i$ are functions, not variables.

Comment: I am sorry. I still don't get it. Take an integral on the circle, you are saying we cannot  change variables, for instance $\omega_1\rightarrow \omega_{2}$, $\omega_2\rightarrow \omega_1+\omega_2$, because $\omega_i$  are functions of $\theta_1$, here?

Comment: @Medo I think he want to say that $\omega_{i}=\omega_{i}(\phi_{1},\cdots,\phi_{n})$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's forget about $\theta$ notation here, which confuses. Situation is as follows: There is a diffeomorphism $R^n \to R^n$ which we think of as taking $ (\phi_1,...,\phi_n) \to w=(w_1,...,w_n)  $. We are trying to "pull back" an integration in $w$ variables to $\phi$ variables. The suggested formula would gives give change of variables for integration over open subsets of $R^n$. That is very important. Notice how your Jacobian is the full Jacobian on the whole space.

However, you are integrating over a submanifold. For example, it should not matter how the map $\phi \to w$ distorts along radii perpendicular to the sphere -- an example diffeomorphism (around an annulus containing the sphere) is $x \to |x|^2 x$ which when restricted to sphere is the identity map.

A correct change of variable will involve the Jacobian of the restriction of the map $\phi \to w$ to the sphere. I think to compute the Jacobian you can look at the derivative map (matrix) and then restrict it to the tangent plane to the sphere and then it is linear map $R^{n-1} \to R^{n-1}$. The determinant of the latter should be the right Jacobian.

Here is a concrete example in $S^1 \subset R^2$:
[image]

Comment: I integrated $d \mathcal{H}^1$ on the circle. I don't know for sure what formula you are referring to. Please specify.