# An integration on the sphere (a rescaling problem)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, spherical-harmonics

Let $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and
let $f$ be smooth on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Is it  possible to express the integral

$$I(\lambda):=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}f(\lambda x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n) d\sigma(x),\qquad \lambda >0$$

in terms of the integral
$$J:=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n) d\sigma(x).$$

This is a very simple special case of the my old question here
[Changing variables in integration over spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783690/changing-variables-in-integration-over-spheres)

Some thought: If the point $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ lives on the sphere
$x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1$ then $(\lambda x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ lives on
the ellipsoid $E_{\lambda}:=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n: x_1^2/\lambda^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1\}$.

So, I am guessing
$$I(\lambda):=\int_{E_{\lambda}}f( x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n) d\tilde{\sigma}(x)\qquad (1)$$
where $d\tilde{\sigma}$ is the surface measure on the ellipsoid $E_\lambda$.

**An edit**:

Thanks to the comments below I realize the question so put does not make sense. So, I modify:
Can we express $I(\lambda)$ in terms of $J$
where
$$J:=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n) d\widetilde{\sigma}(x)$$
where $d\widetilde{\sigma}$  is some kind of a weighted surface measure on the sphere, obviously realted to the natural measure $d{\sigma}$ ?

Comment: Are you asking "Does the integral of $f$ over the unit sphere determine the integral of $f$ over a sphere squashed or stretched along one axis?" with no conditions on $f$ (except integrability on a suitable subset of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$)?

Comment: Precisely yes. Thanks for taking interest in the question..

Comment: Well, here's your first obstacle: what if $f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is $1$ if $x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2 = 1$, and $0$ otherwise??

Comment: If by some luck you can integrate $x_1^k (\partial^k f/ \partial x_1^k)(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ over the sphere for $k = 0, 1, \dots$ you can try to develop $I(\lambda)$ as a Taylor series about $\lambda = 1$, but to answer your question, no.

Comment: @ A rural reader. Why should we look at those deivatives. please explain..there is a missing $ somewhere in your comment, please correct it.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov. Ok. Take such a function. Then $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}f(x_1,...,x_n)=|\mathbb{S}^{n-1}|$ while   $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}f(\lambda x_1,...,x_n)=0$ for any $\lambda\neq 1$. This is correct. But you are missing something important:

Comment: @Misha Lavrov. $f(\lambda x_1,...,x_n)$ and $f( x_1,...,x_n)$ will not be integrated on the same surface, will they ?

Comment: @Medo Aren't you integrating $I(\lambda)$ and $J$ on the same surface??

Comment: @Misha Lavrov. All right. I understand your point. I will require $f$ to be continuous.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov. In any case,  Is (1) correct ?

Comment: The reason the answer is emphatically _no_, even with the modification, is that the "squashed" spheres are mutually disjoint except for a set of measure zero. Since there's no constraint on $f$, there's no control over the integrals $I(\lambda)$. The measure we put on the unit sphere is immaterial: It's like asking "If we know $J=\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y_0)\,dx$ for some $y_0>0$, can we express $I(\lambda)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x, \lambda y_0)\, dx$ in terms of $J$?"

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang. This makes sense. I totally agree with you. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang you should post this as answer!

Comment: What is possible, however, is to relate $\int_{E_1} f(\lambda x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) d\sigma_1(x)$ with $\int_{E_\lambda} f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) d\sigma_2(x)$. If $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ are chosen properly, these two integrals are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is *no*, even with the modification: The "stretched" or "squashed" spheres (gray) are mutually disjoint except for a set of measure zero (the equatorial $S^{n-2}$ where $x_{1} = 0$, shown in blue). Since there's no constraint on $f$, there's no control over the integrals $I(\lambda)$.

[image: Stretched spheres]

The only hope we have in this type of situation, possibly using a suitable $\lambda$-dependent measure on the unit sphere, is when working with functions $f$ whose value on the sphere determines the values on the transformed set.

(One other tangential point: If we integrate the constant function $1$ over the unit circle, we get the arc length $2\pi$. If we integrate the same constant function over a stretched sphere, we may well obtain the arc length of an ellipse, a non-elementary function of $\lambda$.)